# No push notifications are being sent

Tags: parse-platform

I had a problem with push notifications.
Each time I send a push notification from parse.com
I have 1 in the target audience, when I click to send notification.
I have the new notification in the status, but with 0 pushes sent for all 5 notifications I made.

Here is the notifications I sent from parse.com
[image: pushes]
I have 2 devices installed, and 0 sent pushes.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you give further details about your platform?

Comment: I am working on android with parse. The whole android part was setup, and I can see the installation id for the app running on my phone. But the deviceToken, pushType and GCM sender are undefined ( could be source of the problem :/ ). When I go to make a push notification, the website say it clear that it will be sent to 1 audience, but at the status 0 pushes sent for all time.

Comment: Then it's probably a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367362/i-cant-receive-push-notifications-in-app-from-parse, see if you can resolve from what's said there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot receive Parse push notifications on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004770/cannot-receive-parse-push-notifications-on-android)

Comment: after waste of time, it was a package name miss spelling ....

Comment: this is why you should always put the code in questions (though I don't like to put my package names), but also copying it and censoring it could have you make noticed the mistake.
Glad you resolved it though.

Comment: thanks, and sorry for your time.